# Using custom cursor in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

Let's say I have a cursor named myCur.cur.  What I would like to do is use that cursor on my desktop application instead of the boring cursor provided by Visual Studio 2005.  How do I write for that?

Answer (score 2):

If you're targeting WinForms, load a cursor file (the one with the ".cur" extension) that you created

```
Cursor myCursor = new Cursor("myCursor.cur");
```

then assign it as the cursor on any of your controls:

```
myControl.Cursor = myCursor;
```

For additional information on how to do more than this, and create your cursor programmatically instead of loading it from a file, then check out [this tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-how-to-use-custom-cursors).

Should you be or become interested in how to do this in WPF, there's also [an article](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-custom-cursors) to this regard.